# What is the formal proof that adding and multiplying the same number to both sides of an equation yields and equivalent equation?

Tags: calculus, field-theory

More specifically, for fields we define the properties we expect of addition and multiplication. To prove that $x*0=0$ for every $x$ of the field we use the field axioms as well as the concept of adding and multiplying both sides by the same number to prove the identity. As in:

$$
x*0=x*(0+0)=x*0+x*0 \qquad |-x*0
$$

$$
0=x*0
$$

The only case you can't multiply is by zero, as you wont obtain an equivalent equation.

So how is the concept of adding and multiplying both sides of an equation defined? Where does it arise? How do we prove it?

Comment: Are you asking why $a=b$ implies $a+c=b+c$ and $ac =bc$ for any $c$?  For subtraction use the additive inverse and for division (except by $0$) use the multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Exactly. Does this follow from the field axioms?

Comment: I would say that it arises from the properties of equality.  Suppose x=y.  Choose any function f: AxB -> C.   f(x,c) = f(x,c) by the reflexive property.   Now, by substitution f(x,c) = f(y,c).  I think we proved this in my first logic class.  (I think it's in "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliott Mendelson.)

Comment: $x=y \implies x+a=y+a$ by the very general [substitution property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties). $x+a=y+a \implies x=y$ by the [field axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) which guarantee that the additive inverse $\,(-a)\,$ exists, then $x + a + (-a) = y+ a + (-a)$.